# How to set the value of a html input file element in the html page of the web browser control?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, file-upload, webbrowser-control

How to set the value of the html input file element in the html page of the web browser control?

For example:

For the html input element,

```
<input type="text" name="userName" maxlength="10" value="" id="Login_userName">
```

we have code in C# as follows for setting value to input type text:

```
//Assigning value to a textbox control
wbEfile.Document.GetElementById("Login_userName").SetAttribute("value", access.pannumber.ToString());
```

Now, my question is how to set value for an html input element of the type file (given below) ?

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" value="" id="UploadReturn_uploadFile">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The input type="file" has security around it so that you can't directly access the file from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Login_userName");
 if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = access.pannumber.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving a late answer for future references. If the goal is to supply a file name to `<input type="file"/>` element for UI testing automation purposes, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18691219/1768303) it can be done.