# Uploading Files Not Working - Need Assistance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file-upload, webbrowser-control

I am trying to upload a file (an image) using the WebBrowser control. Can't seem to do it and need some help.

Here is the Html:

```
<form action="https://post.testsite.com/k/IOkurrwY4xGI_EJMbjF5pg/zMNsR" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="cryptedStepCheck" value="U2FsdGVkX18yNzEwMjcxMJdrv2IidjtpGSCPzHNblWk02eJAJ6DFXFXic-Am1lTPMYL7k7XDoH0">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="add">
    <input class="file" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple">
    <button class="add" type="submit" name="go"  value="add image">add image</button>
</form>
```

Here is the C# code...

```
        elements = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement file in elements)
        {
            if (file.GetAttribute("name") == "file")
            {
                file.Focus();
                file.InvokeMember("Click");
                SendKeys.Send("C:\\Images\\CCPhotoID.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
            }
        }
```

Note that the file upload button comes up, but can't input any filename into the file name area.

Comment: This is a testing automation script

Comment: That might be a browser security restriction. Are you able to do `SendKeys` into anything else but `<input type=file>`?

Comment: Yes, I am able to use send keys. Apparently, someone has claimed that they can do this - I just can't recreate it - here is the Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696750/submit-file-in-form-from-c-sharp

Comment: You can do this using Selenium WebDriver using the IEDriver - here is the code:                                                                            element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("file"));
             element.SendKeys("C:\\Images\\CCPhotoID.jpg");

Comment: Selenium automates an out-of-process instance of IE, so it sends the keys to whatever IE window currently has focus (*Choose File* dialog in this case). Check my answer for a solution that works for `WebBrowser`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, what you're trying to do is indeed a legit scenario for UI testing automation. IIRC, in early versions of IE it was possible to populate the `<input type="file"/>` field with a file name, without showing up the `Choose File` dialog. For security reason, this is no longer possible, so you have to send keys to the dialog.

The problem here is that `file.InvokeMember("Click")` shows a modal dialog, and you want the keys to be sent to *that* dialog, but `SendKeys.Send` gets executed *after* the dialog has been closed (it's modal, after-all). You need to let the dialog open first, then send the keys and let it close.

This problem can be solved using WinForms `Timer`, but I'd prefer using `async/await` and `Task.Delay` for this (working code):

```
async Task PopulateInputFile(HtmlElement file)
{
    file.Focus();

    // delay the execution of SendKey to let the Choose File dialog show up
    var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
        SendKeys.Send("C:\\Images\\CCPhotoID.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    file.InvokeMember("Click"); // this shows up the dialog

    await sendKeyTask;

    // delay continuation to let the Choose File dialog hide
    await Task.Delay(500); 
}

async Task Populate()
{
    var elements = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement file in elements)
    {
        if (file.GetAttribute("name") == "file")
        {
            file.Focus();
            await PopulateInputFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```

IMO, this approach is very convenient for UI automation scripts. You can call `Populate` like this, for example:

```
void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    Populate().ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Form populated!");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :] If you're interested in more details on how Task.Delay works, you may want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18587810/1768303).

Comment: Hi, how to do this on VB.NET? I try to convert this code on Telerik Converter, but i dont have sucess :/

Answer (score 2):

Just simple like that

```
 elements = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement file in elements)
        {
            if (file.GetAttribute("name") == "file")
            {
                SelectFile();
                file.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
```

> Make this function and call it before click it will work perfectly

```
 public async void SelectFile()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            SendKeys.Send("C:\\Images\\CCPhotoID.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
        }
```

and no triming character error as I faced [Take a look on this I was posted this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454859/uploading-files-not-working-trim-the-initial-characters/39487521#39487521)

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments, got mine program working, the key is to execute the sendKey before opening the file dialog!