# Add cookie to WebBrowser inside custom control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cookies, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to share a session cookie between my `HttpWebRequest` and `WebBrowser` control. It was working fine until I moved the `WebBrowser` into a custom control.

When I try to add the cookie, it does not get set. I have confirmed the value of the cookie I'm sending, it just doesn't add to the browser's cookie string.

Cookie is generated:

```
// cookieJar used for the previous HttpWebRequest
CookieCollection cc = cookieJar.GetCookies(the_url);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Cookie cook in cc)
{
    sb.Append(cook.ToString() + ";");
}
// Confirmed cookie value below is correct: "PHPSESSID=21....";
return sb.ToString();
```

Cookie is sent to custom control:

```
// bc is my custom BrowserControl()
bc.add_cookie(c); // Fails in here
```

Cookie is added to WebBrowser (not working):

```
// Custom control method
public void add_cookie(string c)
{
    // I check both values here - all looks correct
    browser.Document.Cookie = c;
    // I check both values again here - nothing has changed
}
```

Browser's cookie value (before and after - no change occurs):

```
// google analytics cookie (I believe)
__utma=323...; __utmb=235235...; __utmz=25235.236523.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=42346346
```

Keep in mind this code was working before I moved the WebBrowser to a custom control. If there's no solution I can revert the changes but I am trying to avoid that.

In short: Why isn't the cookie being added to the WebBrowser only when it's inside a custom control?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem. More code please.

Comment: I've included everything that is related. Up to the line where the browser cookie is actually set, everything works as expected. What code do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies is not everything, there's also session authentication cache which you cannot copy. `WebBrowser` uses [`UrlMon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library, so the right way of doing this would be to use other `UrlMon` APIs like [`URLOpenStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`URLDownloadToCacheFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This approach allows to download any resource on the same session with the `WebBrowser` control. The `UrlMon` APIs can be called from C# via P/invoke, here is [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025793/1768303). It is also possible to [upload data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764708/1768303) on the same session.

Comment: It was working when the `WebBrowser` was just a control on the form. It only stopped working when I made it into a custom control along with some other controls.

Comment: @MrWednesday, is that a fact it continues working when you revert it back to not using a custom control, or are you just assuming this?

Comment: No, I didn't say it will work if reverted. I said it worked before being converted to a custom control using the setup I described in my question. I have just reverted the code and indeed it is still not working. It appears that the issue is not related to being in a custom control. A (not so)happy coincidence.

Comment: @MrWednesday, I don't think you can reliably share the session/cookies between `WebBrowser` and other HTTP client APIs, besides by using `UrlMon` as described in my answer.

Comment: Can you advise why it was working previously however now is not?

Comment: @MrWednesday, the same thing: coincidence. As already mentioned, there are other things in HTTP protocol which make a particular HTTP session *unique*, besides cookies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48790/discussion-between-mr-wednesday-and-noseratio)

Comment: @MrWednesday, that's pretty much everything I could contribute to help with this question. If you need more details about how HTTP session works, refer to [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).