# How to post data to a web server using wpf webbrowser

Tags: c#, php, wpf, webbrowser-control

I want to get data from a database and use it to login a user to a web site.

I have a wpf page that holds a web browser control. and I have this code that login user to web site which is written in php:

```
<form action='http://www.asite.net/index.php' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
$user = $_GET['u'];
$pass = $_GET['p'];
echo "<input type='text' name='user' value='$user'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='pass' value='$pass'>";
?>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

How can I do this in wpf? As far as I can understand, I need to create an html and post it to site.

My questions:

1- How can I create such html in code?

2- How can I automatically submit it to the site (assuming I am doing this on constructor of a wpf user control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, your goal is to log in and keep the session active inside the `WebBrowser`. If so, you have a few options:

- First, navigate the `WebBrowser` to `www.asite.net`, to establish the session.
- Then obtain the [underlying WebBrowser ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18289217/1768303) and use [`IWebBrowser2::Navigate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, it has `PostData` parameter which allows to do an HTTP POST request.
- Or, [inject and execute some JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002650/1768303) which would use [XHR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to post the form the AJAX way.
- Or, use `WebBrowser.Document` as `dynamic` to create a hidden `form` element, populate it and submit it, in the same way you'd do with `JavaScript`.
- Or, use [COM `XMLHTTP`object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send a POST request, it shares the session with the `WebBrowser`.
- You could also use [some low level UrlMon API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764708/1768303) to send a POST request.

**Updated**, here is an example of creating and submitting a :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigatedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = delegate
        {
            this.webBrowser.Navigated -= handler;

            dynamic document = this.webBrowser.Document;
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.action = "http://requestb.in/tox7drto";
            form.method = "post";

            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "name_1";
            input.value = "value_1";
            form.appendChild(input);

            input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "submit";
            form.appendChild(input);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            input.click();
        };

        this.webBrowser.Navigated += handler;
        this.webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like to know how can I create a form and post it (using the technique as you said in your 4th suggestion). Can you please elaborate or give some reference so I can do some study about it?

Comment: @mans, I noticed a bunch of other recent `WebBrowser`-related questions from you. You've probably figured out how to do manipulate the form, have you?

Comment: Not yet! I am doing some hacks for it to work, but it is an ugly way of doing this and I like to find a better way. In current implementation, I read web page, find form, fill fileds and then using javascript, click on all buttons and post it back. I lke to find a way to create the form on my code and post it without reading it from server as I know what is the format of form. Any suggestion on how to create a form and post it to server?

Comment: @mans, check the update. This is as much as I could help with this question.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can get it from here!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Net` namespace, particularly the `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` objects.

See this previous answer, it should get you started:

[How to programmatically fill a form and post a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26881/2382032)

Comment: Thanks, but then if I open the web Brower to point to the same url, is it still shows as a logged-in user or not? I think now, webRequest doesn't pas login cookie to webbrowser. I am wrong?

Comment: Correct, different sandbox. Are you looking to open a browser, automatically fill it in and then post?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to open a webbrowser which is hosted inside my wpf application and use login information to login to the web site and show the output to user so he can work there.

Comment: Check out the [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx). You may need to do some funky stuff to post though, like use the [UI Automation Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.aspx) to fill out the form and post.