# Upload file via WebBrowser

Tags: c#, file-upload, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to figure out how to upload a file via WebBrowser, found [`this`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28917/Setting-a-file-to-upload-inside-the-WebBrowser-com) alternative to code below . I tried for hours but I couldn't make this working. Would someone point out what's wrong with the implementation?

I'm using this (pretty bad, since it requires the application to be on front of all):

```
HtmlElement file = browser.Document.GetElementById("file");
file.Focus();
SendKeys.Send(filePath + "{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Trying to use `javascript` form handlers from the early 2000's might not be prudent.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18691219/1768303