# Uploading Files Not Working - trim the initial characters

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file-upload, webbrowser-control

I am trying to upload a file using the WebBrowser control. It trims the starting character sometimes one and sometimes three then choose window gives error `Invalid file name!`. Can't seem to do it and need some help.

Here is the Html:

```
    <input name="UploadedFile" id="UploadedFile" type="file" />
    <input name="up" id="up" type="button" value="Upload" />
```

Here is the vb code:

```
Dim el = elc.GetElementsByName("UploadedFile")
el.Item("UploadedFile").Focus()
'    SendKeys.Send("Capture.png" & "{ENTER}")
SendKeys.Send("C:\Capture.png" + "{ENTER}")
el.Item("UploadedFile").InvokeMember("Click")
```

that the file upload button comes up and hit enter, but can't input full filename into the file name area.

If I use this`SendKeys.Send("C:\Capture.png" + "{ENTER}")`. It gives this error:
[Choose window error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlyi9.png)

If I use this `SendKeys.Send("Capture.png" + "{ENTER}")`. It gives this error:
[Choose window error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oObLv.png)

And if I put extra character then it works fine but it doesn't always trim one character so I can't put an extra character to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right @soohoonigan the sendkeys comes up too fast but that is not an answer for that. I did this like that.

Here is my code:

```
Dim el = elc.GetElementsByName("UploadedFile")
SetFile()
el.Item("UploadedFile").InvokeMember("Click")

Public Async Sub SetFile()

       Await Task.Delay(1000)
       SendKeys.Send("c:\Capture.png" & "{ENTER}")

End Sub
```

It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the sendkeys comes up too fast behind focus, so the first few characters don't get picked up. Try just filling the textbox all at once with one line by setting the textbox's value rather than trying to imitate user keystrokes, this could replace both the focus and sendkeys lines:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UploadedFile").SetAttribute("value", "C:\Capture.png")
```

...and then call the button-click

Comment: Do you mean the text still gets cut off? If so, does your code execute once the page has completely loaded or does it immediately follow the navigate command?

Comment: I have tried this. It didn't work. For security reason, this is no longer possible.

Comment: I execute the code after page has completely loaded

Comment: anyway, thank you. You are right sendkeys comes up too fast. I did it I will post my Answer @soohoonigan